# NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:path append:NO has no space available

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa, ios8

I am creating an output stream with:

```
[NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:audio.filePath append:NO]
```

But afterwards this stream is:

```
[out hasSpaceAvailable]
```

returning `nil`

I am running on the simulator. The hard drive has space and I can confirm the parent directory exists.

Any ideas on why this is happening?

NB: On Xcode 5 / iOS7 simulator the same code did not return `nil` here

Comment: Return type of `hasSpaceAvailable` is `BOOL`, not `id`.  
So it would be `YES` or `NO`, but not `nil`. Anyway, did you `open` the stream?

Comment: Maybe you should check `out` itself is `nil`.

Comment: To clarify, `out` is not nil. Getting "nil" from debugger with `po [out hasSpaceAvailable]` which is human readable as "NO"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to open the stream first.

Just tested with the following code, and it works:

```
NSOutputStream *outstream = [NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:@"/tmp/out.test" append:NO];
[outstream open];
NSLog(@"hasSpaceAvailable: %@", [outstream hasSpaceAvailable] ? @"YES" : @"NO");
```

Outputs:

```
hasSpaceAvailable: YES
```

Comment: Can you confirm it is not working without `[outstream open]`?

Comment: Yes, I confirm that without the open call hasSpaceAvailable returns NO.